Next.js (react) to format date and time using moment or not
what is best for my next front-end app to handle date format using  Moment.js or JS functions? Data come from the backend in the date type and I want it to appear in a readable format according to performance and loading time.
Mon Apr 01 2024 14:47:56 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00) 

This  must  format to:
01/04/2024 02:48 pm


Problem :

Format date using library or manually using Javascript

Possible Solution :

If you need date formatting just once or twice in few pages, (in your whole project) then do it manually.

If there are multiple formats needed or logic needed to convert date is getting complex then use library which will save time & it will also reduce code to almost one line (depending on conditions).

Also size of library is small & offers many functionality.

You may further also look at functions provided by library which will help you deciding.


Small Example to demonstrate ease of use (make necessary changes wherever required):


let From = new Date("Mon Apr 01 2024 14:47:56 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)");
console.log("With Library :")
console.log(moment(From).format("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm a"))
// LIBRARY HANDLES ACCORDING TO SPECIFIED FORMAT

console.log("\n")

console.log("Without Library :")
console.log(`${From.getDate()}/${From.getMonth()+1}/${From.getFullYear()} ${From.getHours() % 12  || 12}:${From.getMinutes()} ${From.getHours() > 12 ? "pm" : "am"}`)

// HERE I HAD TO HANDLE 12HR. FORMAT & ALSO AM PM
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.30.1/moment.min.js"></script>



Please Read :

Format : https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

